# Catch UITaBbarViewController item selection to make decision of showing it

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I need to catch UITabBarController item selection for the case when user taps on camera item and app requests permissions and if permissions not granted then not show Camera VC. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
              shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
   if viewController is YourVC {

   }
   else {}

}
```

And conform to `UITabBarControllerDelegate`